# Install built meteor package

Tags: meteor

I built the meteor package as follow:
meteor build /tmp

It built the jar.gz file.

Now How do install this on different server?

Thanks

Comment: May be this will help you.
https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Answer (score 0):

1. upload the tar file using ftp or scp on the terminal.
2. untar it on the server
3. cd bundle/programs/server
4. npm install
5. node bundle/main.js

Additional info:

1. use pm2 on the server so you can manage the node process seamlessly.

**OR**

2. use forever to run your app even if you quit the terminal.